# SQL Exclude Records with Leveling

Tags: sql, oracle

For example, I have a table like this:

```
+---------+-------+----------+
| sort_id | level | security |
+---------+-------+----------+
|       1 |     1 | A        |
|       2 |     2 | A        |
|       3 |     3 | U        |
|       4 |     4 | A        |
|       5 |     5 | A        |
|       6 |     3 | A        |
|       7 |     4 | U        |
|       8 |     5 | A        |
|       9 |     6 | A        |
|      10 |     7 | A        |
|      11 |     3 | A        |
|      12 |     3 | A        |
+---------+-------+----------+
```

Security column is A for Authorized and U for Unauthorized. I need to exclude those records under the Unauthorized records based on their level.
For a better picture of the SQL records, it looks like this:
[image]

Those pointed with arrow are the Unauthorized records and we should exclude those under it.

So the SQL result should be the following table:

```
+---------+-------+----------+
| sort_id | level | security |
+---------+-------+----------+
|       1 |     1 | A        |
|       2 |     2 | A        |
|       3 |     3 | U        |
|       6 |     3 | A        |
|       7 |     4 | U        |
|      11 |     3 | A        |
|      12 |     3 | A        |
+---------+-------+----------+
```

How can we produce it using a simple Select statement? Thanks in advanced! Just comment if something is unclear.

Comment: What is this supposed to mean:  "I need to exclude those records under the Unauthorized records based on their level. "  Can you better explain this logic?

Comment: I have edited my question with a diagram, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand "under the unauthorized records" as meaning a sequence of records with increasing id`s following the unauthorized records (based on the id), then here is an approach:

```
select sort_id, level, security
from (select t.*, min(case when authorized = 'U' then id end) over (partition by grp) as minuid
      from (select t.*,
                   (row_number() over (order by id) - level) as grp
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
where id > minuid;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, it works perfectly! By the way, I want to understand the Select statement you made. If it's ok, can you explain it to me? And, I'm not familiar with "over", "partition by", "row_number()". Thanks alot!

Comment: @ryandy  These are called "analytic functions" and are a very powerful part of SQL (and available in databases besides Oracle).  The place to start is with the documentation:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm.